# setting target attribute of form in Symfony2 FormBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, formbuilder

I need to set my form's `target` attribute in `Symfony2` using `FormBuilder`.
I tried this:

```
$fb = $this->createFormBuilder();
$fb->setAttribute('target', '_top');
```

but it doesnt work!
Why?
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass it as a constructor argument (among options) as such:

```
$fb = $this->createFormBuilder(null, array('attr' => array('target' => '_top')));
```

Remember to pass your form model data (if any) as first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Debreczeni's answer; you can define the default options in your form class:

```php
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'attr' => [
            'target' => '_top',
        ],
    ]);
}
```